# showing data in one row (from multiple rows)

Tags: mysql

Below is what I have

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + field1 + field2 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  +  1     +        +
+ 1  +        +   1    +
+ 2  +  1     +        +
+ 2  +        +   2    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I want is

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + field1 + field2 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  +  1     +   1    +
+ 2  +  1     +   2    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to combine the rows and show data for user in one row against multiple rows like I have in table.

Any idea how to do it?

**Note** : I don't have any row who have data for all fields. And I don't have any user with below scenario.

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + field1 + field2 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 3  +  1     +        +
+ 3  +  1     +   1    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Only 1 data in one row and two row per user.

I tried with

```
SELECT id, concat(field1), concat(field2) from myTable
GROUP BY id;
```

but its not coming.

### [data at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5aadf/6)

Comment: You should clarify what it is exactly that you are asking.

Comment: @NathanMann : What is not clear to you?

Comment: I believe that I misread, I've removed the downvote, sorry about that :/

Comment: @NathanMann : Not a problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use one of MySQL's [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html) when aggregating grouped data.  Either use [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in place of (the non-aggregate string function) [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_concat), or else (better for numeric data) use [`SUM()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum):

```
SELECT id, SUM(field1), SUM(field2) FROM myTable GROUP BY id
```

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6452/2)