# finding maximum data from multiple rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, max

Below is what I have

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + field1 + field2 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  +  1     +        +
+ 1  +  23    +        +
+ 1  +        +   1    +
+ 1  +        +   33   +
+ 2  +  55    +        +
+ 2  +        +   2    +
+ 2  +        +   23   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

What I want is

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ id + field1 + field2 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ 1  +  23    +   33   +
+ 2  +  55    +   23   +
++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

I want to combine the rows (with greatest data) and show data for user in one row against multiple rows like I have in table.

Any idea how to do it?

**Note** : I don't have any row who have data for all fields. Only 1 data in one row and two or more rows per user.

I tried with

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(MAX(field1)), GROUP_CONCAT(MAX(field2)) from myTable
GROUP BY id;
```

but its giving error as

```
Invalid use of group function:
```

### [data at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4503b/4)

This question is bit advanced to my earlier question, ***[showing data in one row (from multiple rows)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11272380/showing-data-in-one-row-from-multiple-rows)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id, MAX(field1), MAX(field2) FROM myTable GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple query should do the trick.

```
SELECT id, MAX(field1), MAX(field2)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY id;
```

it groups all the rows with the same id and selects the maximum value within each group for each column